# Prolog - Recursive movement

Tags: prolog

I have made this prolog functions for a pacman game:

```
% I want this to return 0, 1, 2 or 3 to make a move.
other-moves([[Xpacman,Ypacman]], Listpellets, Listwall, Movepacman) :-
   count_pellets_above(Listpellets,A), 
   count_pellets_bellow(Listpellets,B), 
   A > B, 
   repeat, 
   choose(4,2,Movepacman), 
   iswall(Xpacman,Ypacman,Movepacman,Listwall),
   !.
other-moves([[Xpacman,Ypacman]], Listpellets, Listwall, Movepacman) :- 
   count_pellets_above(Listpellets,C), 
   count_pellets_bellow(Listpellets,D), 
   C =< D, 
   repeat, 
   choose(4,3,Movepacman), 
   iswall(Xpacman,Ypacman,Movepacman,Listwall),
   !.

% verifies if the coordinate is a wall.
iswall(Xpacman, Ypacman, Random,Listwall) :- 
   Random==0, 
   X1 is Xpacman-1, 
   (member([X1,Ypacman], Listwall)),
   !.
iswall(Xpacman, Ypacman, Random,Listwall) :- 
   Random==1, 
   X1 is Xpacman+1, 
   (member([X1,Ypacman],Listwall)),
   !.
iswall(Xpacman, Ypacman, Random,Listwall) :- 
   Random==2, 
   Y1 is Ypacman-1, 
   (member([Xpacman,Y1],Listwall)),
   !.
iswall(Xpacman, Ypacman, Random,Listwall) :- 
   Random==3, 
   Y1 is Ypacman+1, 
   (member([Xpacman,Y1],Listwall)),
   !.

% gives a random number
choose(A, C, B) :- 
   repeat, 
   B is random(A), 
   B \= C,
   !.

%count the number of pellets above the coordinate (0,0).
count_pellets_above([],0).
count_pellets_above([[_,Y]|T],N) :- 
   Y>=0, 
   count_pellets_above(T,M), 
   N is M+1,
   !.
count_pellets_above([[_,Y]|T],N) :- 
   Y<0, 
   count_pellets_above(T,M), 
   N is M,
   !.

% count the number of pellets bellow the coordinate (0,0).
count_pellets_bellow([],0).
count_pellets_bellow([[_,Y]|T],N) :- 
   Y=<0, 
   count_pellets_bellow(T,M), 
   N is M+1,
   !.
count_pellets_bellow([[_,Y]|T],N) :- 
   Y>0, 
   count_pellets_bellow(T,M), 
   N is M,
   !.
```

I want other-moves to return a number different from a move to a wall. I don't know why other-moves is returning false instead of a number when I make this command:

```
other-moves([[1,2]],[[]],[[1,3]],C).
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`other-moves` isn't a valid Prolog identifier. It's parsed as

```
other - moves([[Xpacman,Ypacman]], Listpellets, Listwall, Movepacman)
```

so you're effectively defining `-` on the atom `other` and certain `moves/4` terms.

Use an underscore instead of a dash.